# Generalize regex to search for Wikipedia Categories

Tags: python, regex, wikipedia

I have the following string of text (taken from the Wikipedia dumps)

```
text = "[[Category:Ethnic groups| ]]\n[[Category:Ethnic groups by region|*]]\n[[Category:Society-related lists|Ethnic groups]]\n[[Category:Lists of ethnic groups]]"
```

and I would like to extract all the categories in the text. So basically the ideal output should be

```
text = "[Ethnic groups,Ethnic groups by region,Society-related lists|Ethnic groups,Lists of ethnic groups]"
```

This is my attempts at getting the solution

```
import re

categories = re.findall(r'\b(Category:.*)\b', text)

categories = [category.replace("Category:", "") for category in categories]
```

which returns what I want. However, I'm not sure this is the best way to generalize the regular expression. In particular, I would like to search for "[[Category:" instead of just "Category:" because that's the actual Wikipedia definition for the category links. Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve my regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to make a research and after a replacement, you can do it in one step using a capture group *(`re.findall` returns only capture groups when the pattern contains capture groups, otherwise it returns the whole match)*.

Looking for `[[Category:` instead of `\bCategory:` is probably a good idea. All you have to do is to escape opening square brackets since they are special regex characters.

Instead of `.*\b` you should use something more restrictive like `(?:\|(?!\*)[^\]|]*)*)` that excludes the closing square bracket and the pipe followed by an asterisk. However using `.*\b` is also a good idea if you are sure that the data you want to extract ends with a word character and if there is only one `[[Category:...]]` per line. A good compromise will be `[^\]]*\b`

So in one step:

```
categories = re.findall(r'\[\[Category:([^\]]*\b)', text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with :

```
re.findall(r"\bCategory:(.*)\b", text)
```

wich should return only the values needed (thanks to the parenthesis)